# End of tutorial roswtf

Tags: ros, tutorial, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I've followed the tutorial and at the end when I ran roswtf while just roscore is running i ve got some errors! Have a look and tell me if you can help or explain!

```
> @ubuntu:~$ roswtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: bloom -- rosrelease -- 
WARNING You are missing Debian packages for core ROS Python modules: bloom (python-bloom) -- rosrelease (python-rosrelease) -- 

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rosout:
   * /rosout


Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method TCPServer.run of <rospy.impl.tcpros_base.TCPServer object at 0x8e55ecc>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 156, in run
    (client_sock, client_addr) = self.server_sock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57458/end-of-tutorial-roswtf/) by [Disd](https://answers.ros.org/users/4376/disd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the first part still show up while not running roscore? I had the same problem and if it does, it simply means you have to install python-bloom and python-rosrelease. Simply put these in, then reopen the terminal and run roswtf. Hope this helps!

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-bloom
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosrelease
```

---

Originally posted by [RoboCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4477/robocd/) with karma: 66 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_Greenhand](https://answers.ros.org/users/14596/ros_greenhand/) on 2014-04-08**:
Thank you for helping the similar problems.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-02-08**:
not working on melodic, I can only install python bloom, python-rosrelease is not found, and the bad descriptor error reappears anyway (ubuntu 18.04LTS)